Майнкрафт Шейдеры: как отключить лунный свет?
В ванильном Манкрафт даже ночью луна освещает все блоки 4-мя единицами света. Мне нужно это отключить! Я пишу свой шейдер для версии 1.20-1.21, как и в каком файле я могу это сделать?
